# how do I auto move an image in a loop, at the click of a button using JS?

Tags: javascript, function, animation

I'm trying to write a function that moves my image of a face from one side of a container to the other in a loop, at the click of a button. I need a function in JavaScript, that auto-moves/animates the object(image) to move horizontally in my container. Everytime I click the start button or even refresh the page, I haven't been able to even move my image. I'm stuck and help would be much appreciated. My code is below so can i please get feedback. My Javascript, html and css are on separate file.

```
var start = anime({
      targets: 'img.face',
      translateX: [{
          value: 100,
          duration: 1200
        },
        {
          value: 0,
          duration: 800
        }
      ],
      rotate: '1turn',
      duration: 2000,
      loop: true
    });

    document.querySelector('button').onclick = start.play();

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    body {
      text-align: center;
    }

    button {
      color: red;
      background: lightblue;
      font-family: Impact, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    }

    .face {
      position: relative;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }

    #container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 500px;
      background: aqua;
      border: 20px lightpink solid;
      margin: 20px 150px 20px 150px;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div>
      <button id="start">Start</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
      <img class="face" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/jemastock/jemastock1705/jemastock170504269/77700505-color-pencil-cartoon-front-view-face-guy-with-hairstyle-vector-illustration.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: And where do you include `anime.js`?

Comment: I edited your question to make it partially functional in the question.  Now please include the content of `game.js` that makes this more functional, see how it now gives an error on `anime` "Uncaught ReferenceError: anime is not defined",

Comment: Please also refine your question.  Is it the moving you have a challenge with? Calling the function to do so? Where are you blocked in your resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = start.play();
```

To

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = start.play;
```

You should only assign the function to the onclick, without calling it. Otherwise if we be called immediately when parsed.